# VB.NET - How to block user input on a windows form without graying it out?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, input

I am trying to block any sort of user input on a modal dialog that can be used to perform a slow operation that takes a few minutes to finish. The only solution for this which I found so far is to simply set the form's `Enabled` property to `false`, however that also grays out the entire form. In addition to that it also for some reason prevents me from showing a wait cursor because that only seems to work while the form is not disabled.
How can I block any user input on my form while the operation is not finished without graying the form out and while still allowing me to set a wait cursor?

Comment: How about modally showing an additional form with a rolling statusbar? Or you could set your form into processing mode using a form level property and ignore all input while in processing mode.

Comment: put all controls on a panel and disable the panel. If you want also the controls to become grayed when the panel is disable than you have to loop to all controls on the panel and put them readonly. You could make your own panel for that and put your own panel in the toolbox

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to block any sort of user input

User input is sent to the application in the form of window's messages.  You can install a filter to block the messages related to keyboard and mouse input.  This is done by defining a class that implements the [IMessageFilter Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter) and the filter is installed by calling [Application.AddMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter) and passing an instance of the class.

The following defines a class that implements `IMessageFilter`.  If the application recieves a message defined in the `FilteredMessages` enum, it will block further processing of that message.  The class is self contained and exposes two static methods:

1. Install
2. Uninstall

---

```
Public Class InputFilter : Implements IMessageFilter
  Private Shared sharedInstance As InputFilter
  Private handledMessages As FilteredMessages() = CType([Enum].GetValues(GetType(FilteredMessages)), FilteredMessages())

  Private Sub New()
  End Sub

  Private Enum FilteredMessages
#Region "Keyboard"
    WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
    WM_KEYUP = &H101

    WM_SYSKEYDOWN = &H104
    WM_SYSKEYUP = &H105
#End Region

#Region "Mouse"
    WM_LBUTTONDOWN = &H201
    WM_LBUTTONUP = &H202
    WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = &H203

    WM_RBUTTONDOWN = &H204
    WM_RBUTTONUP = &H205
    WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK = &H206

    'prevent interaction with title bar
    WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = &HA1
    WM_NCLBUTTONUP = &HA2
    WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = &HA3

    WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN = &HA4
    WM_NCRBUTTONUP = &HA5
    WM_NCRBUTTONDBLCLK = &HA6

    ' prevent mouse hover/enter/move events
    WM_MOUSEHOVER = &H2A1
    WM_MOUSEMOVE = &H200
#End Region
  End Enum

  Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As Message) As Boolean Implements IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage
    Return handledMessages.Contains(CType(m.Msg, FilteredMessages))
  End Function

  Public Shared Sub Install()
    If sharedInstance Is Nothing Then
      sharedInstance = New InputFilter
      Application.AddMessageFilter(sharedInstance)
    End If
  End Sub

  Public Shared Sub Uninstall()
    If sharedInstance IsNot Nothing Then
      Application.RemoveMessageFilter(sharedInstance)
      sharedInstance = Nothing
    End If
  End Sub

End Class
```

To test this class create a new WinForm project and add two Buttons, a Label, and a Textbox to the form in the designer.  Then replace the form's code with the following code.

```
Public Class Form1
  Private tmr As New Timer() With {.Interval = 10000}

  Private tickHandler As EventHandler = Sub(s, e)
                                          tmr.Stop()
                                          RemoveHandler tmr.Tick, tickHandler
                                          InputFilter.Uninstall()
                                          Label1.Text = "filter off"
                                          Application.UseWaitCursor = False
                                        End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    InputFilter.Install()
    Application.UseWaitCursor = True
    AddHandler tmr.Tick, tickHandler
    tmr.Start()
    Label1.Text = "filter on"
    Label1.Refresh()
    TextBox1.Select()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    MessageBox.Show("clicked")
  End Sub

End Class
```

Run the project and click on `Button1`.  The `Button1_Click` handler installs the filter, activates the WaitCursor and starts a timer.  The timer will elapse after ten seconds and will uninstall the filter.  While the filter is active, you will not be able to interact with the form using either the keytboard or mouse.

For information on the filtered messages, see [Mouse Input Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/mouse-input-notifications) and [Keyboard Input Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/keyboard-input-notifications).